# if $f,g:A\times A\rightarrow \mathbb{R},f(x,y)\leq g(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in A$ then $\sup_{x}(\inf_{y}f(x,y))\leq \sup_{x}(\inf_{y}g(x,y))?$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I think that inequality will  not be preserved even inf or sup taken separately but i cant find counterexample if it is not true, if true, i don`t know how to start prove

Comment: Hint: For every $x$ we have $\inf_y f(x,y) \leq \inf _y g(x,y)$.

Comment: then can i take  $f'(x)= \inf_{y}f(x,y)$ and $g'(x)=\inf_{y}g(x,y)$ then apply sup? it will be hold?

Comment: Yes, (this confused me at first, maybe use a different name ?use tilde? $\tilde{f}$?).

Comment: ok:) $\tilde{f}(x)= \inf_{y}f(x,y)$ and    $\tilde{g}(x)=\inf_{y}g(x,y)$. then $\sup_x \tilde{f}(x) \leq \sup _x \tilde{g}(x)$. this means $\sup_{x}(\inf_{y}f(x,y))\leq \sup_{x}(\inf_{y}g(x,y))$ is true. i see now why i cant find counterexample